# Classification sequence 4D array data with RNN-LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am currently working on a project where i am trying to create a machine learning model that is able to classify actions in a video. I already created a script that is able to detect a person in a video and generate data based on the movements of the body parts. This generates a 4D array with the following input shape:

(nframes, nperson, nbodyparts, 3 coördinates per body part)

The input shape of just 1 video (2 persons) with a duration of 3 second and filmed in 60fps/s will look like this:
(180, 2, 25, 3)

The 4D array for every video is saved as a numpy file, so if i process 400 video's. I will get 400 numpy files.

The next step is to create a keras or tensorflow RNN-LSTM model that is able to train on the 400 numpy files and able to work with the 4D array of every video, but i really don't know how to get this to work. I already searched for some solutions but the only thing i could fine is that Keras is only able to work with 3D array.

I really would appreciate your help and view on how i could solve this, with hopefully an example code.

King regards,

Comment: One of the possible ways is to merge `nbodyparts` and `coordinates` into one dimension, such that the input shape would be `(180, 2, 75)`. Yet, to me, it makes more sense to merge the last three axes into one axis since they are of features whose order are not important.

Comment: Do you by any chance know a tutorial on how to reshape the array, so i could reshape the array to (180,2,75) by merging the nbodyparts and coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using `numpy.array`. Reshaping the 4d array into 3d could be done by `np.resahpe()`. Documentation can be found [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html).

Example:

```
import numpy as np

# create a sample 4d array data of shape (10, 2, 25, 3) 
data = np.arange(10*2*25*3).reshape((10, 2, 25, 3))

# condense the 4d array to 3d array by explicitly stating the shape.
data_reshaped = data.reshape((10, 2, 75))

# or you can use -1 to ask numpy infer the dimension
data_reshaped2 = data.reshape((10, 2, -1))

# you can also reshape your data into 2d of shape (10, 150)
data_reshaped3 = data.reshape((10, -1))
```

Then, you can follow tutorials online to build your model. An example tutorial could be [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/reshape-input-data-long-short-term-memory-networks-keras/).

Note: You mentioned that "Keras is only able to work with the 3D array." I think one of the dimension is reserved for `batch_size`. So, I suggest you should convert your 4d array into 2d.

Comment: Thank you a lot for this approach. I will test it and let you know asap. :)